# Kendo grid dataSource.filter all columns

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendogrid where I want to search three columns from a input field. The logic below will only search one of the columns is there another flag I need to add for it to search all three columns

```
 $('#filter').on('input', function (e) {
                    var grids = $(".k-grid");
                    for (var j = 0; j < grids.length; j++) {
                        var grid = $(grids[j]);
                        var griddata = $(grid).data('kendoGrid');
                        griddata.dataSource.filter(
                            { field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: e.target.value },
                            { field: "Date", operator: "contains", value: e.target.value },
                            { field: "Type", operator: "contains", value: e.target.value });
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use more than one filter, pass them in as an array. You can also set or change the logic.

```
griddata.dataSource.filter({
    logic: "or",
    filters:
    [
        { field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: e.target.value },
        { field: "Date", operator: "contains", value: e.target.value },
        { field: "Type", operator: "contains", value: e.target.value }
    ]});
```